# Can i have multiple views and serializers for single model in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an application in which an owner is posting a job post and multiple user will apply for that job application.

I have provided an endpoint to user to apply for a certain job post and it went successful. Then, I tried to provide a separate endpoint to an owner in which I want to view the application and edit the status of the application. To implement this I used a separate serializer which allows only status field to be updated and making rest of the fields as read only. Additionally, I created the separate view as well for the owner to update the status of the application based on id filter. Lastly, creating two separate URLs as well.

```
<ip-address>/api/job/application (for user)
<ip-address>/api/job/application-status (for owner)
```

But I ended up in a situation where I am getting the same URL for both of the job application endpoint and job application status endpoint because they are using same model.

**Is it possible to have multiple views and serializers for a single model? If Yes, then how can I achieve this and what permissions should I use for owner.**

Comment: It definitely is possible. How have you hooked up the views/viewsets into your API router?

Comment: it's possible, can we have a look to your code ?